# How to correctly sell with take profit and stoploss using TradingView strategy?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I was experimenting with TradingView strategies and set up a strategy to buy and sell after particular profit or loss. But Strategy Tester doesn't seem to react to my profit and stop loss value changes, all the exit orders are the same regardless of the profit or stop loss values. Do you know what might be the problem?

My code:

```
if (indicatorColor == color.orange and strategy.position_size <= 0)
 strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 3)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
 strategy.exit("bracket", "buy", profit=longExitPrice, stop = longStopLossPrice)
```

It's usually like this:

[image]

or like this where the profit is just 1%, when I configured profit and stoploss to be 10%:
[image]

Orders look like these regardless profit or stop loss values:

[image]

Do I understand something wrong or there is a bug?

Comment: We can't tell if you don't show your code on the stop loss.

Comment: @bbnm I changed it to longProfitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.015
longStopLossPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.99 and strategy.exit("bracket", "buy", limit=longProfitPrice, stop = longStopLossPrice). Seems to be working now